# Couldn't reach cloud firestore backend Android (21.3.0)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a bit new to using firestore, and I recently got in to a problem.
I am trying to get a collection back from the server, yet I keep getting an error:

> W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

My code:

onCreateView:

```
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```

A function that is getting called in the onCreateView of a fragment:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("users").
                get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        // Do stuff. When I try to log something from here nothing is coming in
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same with 21.4.0