# Firestore android sdk cannot reach backend server on android 9 and other versions(android N also)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

App is getting error firestore not able to reach backend, internet is working perfectly (can reach google.com), After searching for solutions I found that there is a option of

`firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true });`

in firestore js sdk but not in android, Questions:

1. Is this the right solution
2. Whats the android equivalent

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674

It worked when I changed the network from wifi to cellular, can we achieve this through code, anyhow detect firebase connection is failing then ask user to switch network or programatically change network ?

There exists a unanswered question : [Couldn't reach cloud firestore backend Android (21.3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362485/couldnt-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-android-21-3-0)