# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**My environment**

```
Android Studio version: 3.6.1
Firebase Component: Firestore, Auth
```

**Describe the problem**

App always takes more than 1 minute to login, after login it cannot load firestore data. I checked the logs shown as below:

```
--------------------------Firebase logs---------------------------
    W/Firestore: (21.5.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

. The logs tell that "device does not have a healthy internet connection at the moment", however I'm sure that my WiFi connection is strong, I can play something with youtube. [Same issue reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688604/firestore-android-sdk-cannot-reach-backend-server-on-android-9-and-other-version)

. I searched in Github and saw there is [Same issue on firebase-js-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1674), in this has a workaround solution by set the experimentalForceLongPolling=true. But Android doesn't this option experimentalForceLongPolling.

**. Notice that, issue only occurs when I use WiFi network, if I change to Cellular then issue gone**

```
Gradle file:

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
```

Comment: This error is indicative of connectivity issues. It may be worthwhile checking whether a firewall, or antivirus suite is interfering with your connection to the Firestore back-end. Trying a different WiFi network, or LAN, usually gives significant results. Are-you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: I tried with 2 WiFi connection as below:
- 1st is WiFi Hotspot, I used my test phone (Android phone) for debugging. My test phone connected to WiFi Hotspot of Samsung Galaxy Note 9. Strange thing is during more than 1 month ago  it has no issue, but recently about 1 week the issue happened
- 2nd is my home WiFi, my test phone connected to WiFi AP directly without any firewall, proxy. Both 2 WiFi connection have this issue

Comment: The 2 WiFi connections you describe do not differ radically from those in your initial test. It is worthwhile trying a different connection altogether, on different premises, if possible, to perform a relevant test.

Comment: I'll just add to this for new readers. I also had the same problem and just turning WiFi off then on again on my phone solved the problem. So yes, it is definitely a connectivity issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue but it seems not to work for me even when I use cellular or wifi. what should I do ?   some days ago it was working fine but I is not today